# How many rows are inserted

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to know how many rows are inserted in a table by using SQL only.

For Example: consider 2 tables TT and TT1  and I want to insert into TT1 using TT table like this:

```
INSERT INTO TT1 
SELECT * 
FROM TT 
WHERE 1=1;
```

after executing above statement I want to know how many rows are inserted?  by using Oracle SQL only. Is there any way?

Comment: If `tt1` is empty before that, run `select count(*) from tt1` after the insert. All other solutions will require the use of PL/SQL (so it's not "SQL only" any more)

Comment: Depending on API, something like get diagnostics row_count may be used?

Answer (score 3):

The PL/SQL expression `SQL%ROWCOUNT` may do what you want.  You would need to phrase this as:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TT1 
    SELECT * 
    FROM TT 
    WHERE 1=1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT)
END;
```

In other words, it needs to go into a PL/SQL code block.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TT1 
SELECT * 
FROM TT 
WHERE 1=1;
```

The number of rows inserted are the number of rows returned by the **SELECT** statement. Which is nothing but the count of all the rows of table `TT`, since `1=1` is always **TRUE**, basically filtering nothing.

So, just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TT;
```

**Update** Added an example

For example,

Let's say I have a table **T** which is empty:

```
SQL> create table t as select * from emp;

Table created.
```

I insert rows from **EMP** table to **T**:

```
SQL> insert into t select * from emp;

14 rows created.
```

I want to know how many rows were inserted, which is nothing but the rows returned by the **SELECT** statement.

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
```

This is in pure **SQL**. i.e. you executed an insert, and now want to know how many rows actually inserted by the `INSERT INTO..SELECT`.

However, when you have a lot of insert statements happening programmatically i.e. in **PL/SQL**, then you will need `SQL%ROWCOUNT` for every **INSERT**.

Comment: the above select statement gives total number of rows present in TT. But i want how many rows has been inserted by the insert statement.

Comment: @user3074636 When you do `INSERT INTO ..SELECT` the number of rows inserted into `table_2`is the same as the number of rows fetched by the select on `table_1`. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use PL/SQL you can do it like

```
declare
  i number;
begin
  INSERT INTO TT1 SELECT * FROM TT WHERE 1=1;
  i := sql%rowcount;
end;
```

Otherwise as far as I know there is only way to do it is using SELECT COUNT, if there are records before this query just run **SELECT COUNT** twice, one before executing and one after query then just substract them.